# Using indexOf on ArrayList of type Long returns -1, despite the object existing within the list

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to retrieve the index of a certain Long value that is stored in an ArrayList. But here's what's happening:

[image]

dex is assigned a value of -1 - which I understand means that the object doesn't exist within that arraylist. But as a matter of fact, it does. Here's how I know:

[image]

So the value dex should be assigned is 0.

Where am I messing up?

Edit : `nums` is also an arraylist of type Long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does what? `nums.get(0)` is a `java.lang.String`, as pointed out in your screenshot, while `longList.get(0)` is a `java.lang.Long`.

They are not the same object, indeed `nums.get(0).equals(longList.get(0)) == false`. You must convert the `String` to a `Long` (through `Long.parseLong` for example) and then search for the resulting value inside `longList`

Comment: `nums` is also an arraylist of type Long.

Comment: Then, somewhere in your code, the type safety is broken through reflection or explicit casts or raw types. Otherwise `nums.add("1008")` would raise a compile error.

Comment: Mind that `nums` can't be an `ArrayList<Long>` at runtime. Java has type erasure, an `ArrayList` is always an `ArrayList<Object>` at runtime. Generics are a way to prevent you from the situation you are experiencing: keeping type safety while working with generic containers.

Comment: Okay, thank you! `nums = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(numsString, ",")));` was what was causing the problem, I'm guessing. `numString` stores all the long values in the string format, and with this particular statement, I was trying to seperate the string into different Long elements and store it in `nums` -- which is(was) of type  Long. Now I've just changed `nums` to type string, and I'm using Long.ParseLong.

Comment: Then the answer was _raw types_. Indeed you create a new `ArrayList()` from an `ArrayList<String>` returned by `Arrays.asList`, since `TextUtils.split` returns a `String[]`.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Quite new to programming. These kind of silly mistakes have been head on so far.

Answer (score 0):

So which type is `nums.get()`. If it doesnt return a long type. You can cast it into a long type. But it isnt really  good option. you can also use the Wrapperclass `Long` and its method `Long.parseLong`.

Answer (score 0):

nums is an ArrayList of objects of type String, whereas longList is an ArrayList of objects of type Long. Therefore the statement `longList.indexOf(nums.get(i))` will compare a String object with a Long object, which it will never find.

Try casting the String to a Long e.g. `int dex = longList.indexOf(Long.valueOf(nums.get(i)));`